# Error while opening SQL worksheet in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I am facing the following issue while opening SQL worksheet in SQL developer

Popup with Error Message --> "An error occurred while opening ide.worksheet.file:/C:/users/%USERNAME%/Appdata/Local/Temp/worksheet....."

After clicking on OK I am able to continue work as usual.

I am not able to determine what is causing this problem.
I do not want this pop up coming up every time I start a new worksheet.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: sounds like you don't have write access to the AppData directory - which would be weird. try running SQLDev as an admin user.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.
While running SQL Developer with Run as Administrator option, I was able to open worksheets.